# index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [Sugestao]] - how pass index name to reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, reactive, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am getting the error pasted in this question and it is true: there isn't Sugestao index. The proper name is sugestao (take a note S versus s).

As far as I know, I can't create a index with upper case. So far so good. The issue is: how can "force" spring-data-elasticsearch to search for sugestao instead of Sugestao since my model is a java class in uppercase? I guess it is picking up uppercase automatically.

In Spring-Data-Elasticsearch-3.2.6 (Elastic version 6.x) I can see find has a clear way to set like

```
reactiveElasticsearchOperations.find(
query.build(),
Sugestao.class, // this is the model class
"this_is_my_index_name" //here I can write the name of the index with lower case
)
```

How can I do similar approach in Spring-data-Elasticsearch.4 (Elastic version 7.x) I am trying with search since find is deprecated

```
    Flux<SearchHit<Sugestao>> fluxSearchHits =
            reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(query.build(), Sugestao.class, "sugestao");
```

And I get

The method search(Query, Class, Class) in the type ReactiveSearchOperations is not applicable for the arguments (NativeSearchQuery, Class, String)

Some related sub-questions are:

- it seems in deprecated version of Find I could pass a String and now in search it is expecting a Class. But which class is that to set the index name?
- maybe I can set in other spring-data-elasticsearch config the name of the index or set it to use lowercase an then I can search without adding index name.

  Flux> fluxSearchHits = reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(query.build(), Sugestao.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't have the `@Document` annotation on your entity class?

```
@Document(indexName="sugestao")
public class Sugestao {
  // class stuff
}
```

Then you can call

```
Flux<SearchHit<Sugestao>> fluxSearchHits =
        reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(query.build(), Sugestao.class);
```

If you want to specify the index name explicitly you can use

```
Flux<SearchHit<Sugestao>> fluxSearchHits =
        reactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(query.build(), 
                Sugestao.class, IndexCoordinates.of("sugestao");
```

The [API documentation for `ReactiveSearchOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ReactiveSearchOperations.html) has the different methods documented.